# How can I increase the size of Root Partition?

Tags: root

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS along with Windows 10. I have dedicated 10GB for root directory and now I want to resize the root partition. How can I resize the root?

Comment: Root is on its own partition? You could use Gparted to resize another partition to free up space to increase the root partition's size. (Yes, I realize that sentence is long :))

Comment: Did that answer your question; should I add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If, during the Ubuntu installation, you selected a 10GB partition to be mounted as root (`/`) and another partition for (I'm assuming) `/home`, then you should be able to use Gparted to increase the size of the root partition. Install and open Gparted, find the 10GB partition, and see if there is any free space after it. If so, you can resize it. If not, I believe you can move the partition that is to the right of the root partition. (**This is more risky than usual, so unless you actually need more space, don't do it.**) Resize the last partition on the drive so that it's smaller. Drag all the partition ahead of root to the right, then resize root to fill the empty space.

Questions or problems: comment.